# How do i analyze the running time of a function with a for loop with an if statement?

Tags: python, running-count

For example, let the function consist:

```
def myfunc():
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
       total+=i
       if total >= n:
         return total
    return 0
```

What would the running time be?

I cant seem to figure out a way to analyze this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own decorator, like this:

```
def timed_function(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        import time
        start_time = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = time.time() - start_time
        print("{} took {} seconds to run.".format(f, elapsed))
        return result
    return wrapper


@timed_function
def adding():
    a = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        a = a + 1
    return a

adding()
```

> <function adding at 0x0000023711A0EE50> took 0.49866580963134766 seconds to run.

Edit: Maybe you just need the basics? Then import the time module, and measure before and after running your code, and then print the result. For example:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

#your code goes here

end_time = time.time()
time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
print("Took", time_elapsed)
```

Comment: Nice one, I thought that decorators required a special setup to run.